# Wordpress update_post_field not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Can't get the fields to update with values i'm providing... what's wrong? Custom fields all all created and I see them... just not getting inserted. Using Types plugin to create fields, that's why there's a wpcf prefix.

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 10;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

function get_cords($input) {
    $url = 'http://geocoder.ca/?locate='.urlencode($input).'&geoit=xml';
    $get = get_data($url);
    $result = xml2array($get);
    return $result;
}

function set_ll() {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if ($post->post_type == 'dealer') {

        $dealer = array();
        $dealer['city'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-city', true);
        $dealer['pro'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-pro', true);
        $dealer['pc'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-pc', true);
        $dealer['address'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-address', true);


        $dealer['full'] = $dealer['address'] . ', ' . $dealer['city'] . ', ' . $dealer['pc'] . ', ' . $dealer['pc'];
        $dealer['longlatt'] = get_cords($dealer['full']); 


        if (update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-longitude', $dealer['longlatt']['geodata']['longt'])) {

          update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-latitude', $dealer['longlatt']['geodata']['longt']);

        } 



    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'set_ll');
```

Answer (score 0):

as an assumption from quickly looking at the API docs, try using $post_id as your function's first parameter instead of using global $post

```
function set_ll($post_id) {
  // global $post;
  // $post_id = $post->ID;
  $post = get_post($post_id);
```